# How open Nautilus CD burner as root?

Tags: nautilus, burning

How do I open "Nautilus CD burner" as root from the shell?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more info see the link below

[How to open files as root via a right click](http://www.andrewault.net/2008/12/26/nautilus-as-root-in-ubuntu/)

[Nautilus as Root in Ubuntu](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-open-files-as-root-via-a-right-click/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the actual command used to start the burner, or plain nautilus, at this point. Then, on a command line, enter the following:

Example:

```
 gksudo nautilus
```

Nautilus will then execute with root credentials FOR THIS WINDOW. This should also include other windows that would be opened from THIS nautilus.

Comment: This what I done before - nautilus not show cd